# How to drop a field from a running count

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am tasked with trying to come up with a total count for the number of clients we have had in any given year. I am able to run a total count of the clients we have had, but I want to drop them from the running total when they offboard from us (i.e. @EndDate)

```
DECLARE @EndDate Date
SET @EndDate = (SELECT DISTINCT LOAEndDate FROM tblCompany)   


SELECT DISTINCT Year(DateBecameClient) AS [Year], 
Count(CompanyId) OVER (ORDER BY Year(DateBecameClient)) AS NumberofClients
FROM [tblCompany] AS Company
ORDER BY [Year]
```

Here is the output that I get without including @EndDate.

```
--------------------
Year    NumberofClients
2001    3
2002    6
2003    9
2004    10
2005    13
2006    15
2007    16
2008    26
2009    36
2010    78
2011    135
2012    204
2013    314
2014    385
2015    456
2016    471
2017    496
2018    507
2019    513
2020    514
2021    516
```

Comment: You need to provide sample data in addition to your desired results.

Answer (score 0):

I presume that you have a separate date that indicates when the client left. You'll want to counterbalance with a -1 via a `union`. If a client was added and lost within the same year it'll never be counted:

```
with data as (
    select year(DateBecameClient) as yr, 1 as num
    from tblCompany
    union all
    select year(DateLostClient), -1
    from tblCompany
)
select yr as "Year", sum(sum(num)) over (order by yr) as NumberOfClients
from data
group by yr
order by "Year";
```

I'm using grouping with a sum of sums to get around needing `distinct`. This is basically the same as your query except for the addition of the negative counters.